# notebook and laptop lids controls or settings

Tags: power-management, laptop

ubuntu hi! ***i would like to ask is there any way i can control the lid closing and opening like in windows 10 with my ubuntu 18***? my download always fails using the firefox browser unlike with windows wherein i can change the setting and have my notebook work even when i close my lid. actually, there is a hotkey that make my notebook sleep with my acer aspire3 so i did change the default (sleep is the default). thanks to ubuntu and all who supporters! happy new year!